# How can I inject something into the session when unit testing a service

Tags: grails

I have written a service that reads a CAS session variable ...

```
package cp


import edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

class AuthorizeService {

 def username
 def loginError
 def permissions

 def authCheck( String pageController, String pageAction ) {

  username = getSession().getAttribute(CASFilter.CAS_FILTER_USER)

.....
Omitted the rest of this to save space.  
.....

 }

 private HttpSession getSession() {
  return RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
 }
```

I cannot figure out how to put something into the session in my test so that this piece of code will run.

Here's the test:

```
package cp

import grails.test.*

    class AuthorizeServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {

     def AuthorizeService

     protected void setUp() {
      super.setUp()
     }

     protected void tearDown() {
      super.tearDown()
     }

     void testAuthCheck() {

      def isAuthorized

      // No username in the session
       isAuthorized = AuthorizeService.authCheck( 'welcome', 'index' )
       assertEquals false, isAuthorized

      // Mock the username to the rest of the tests work
       mockSession["CASFilter.CAS_FILTER_USER"] = "testUser" 


    .....
    Omitted the rest of this to save space.  
    .....

     }
```

When I run my test, here's the error I get back:

**No such property: mockSession for class: cp.AuthorizeServiceTests
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: mockSession for class: cp.AuthorizeServiceTests
at cp.AuthorizeServiceTests.testAuthCheck(AuthorizeServiceTests.groovy:26)**

I've been searching Google for 2 days now trying to find a way to inject something into mockSession or something similar so that I can test this service.  I can see where it would be pretty easy to test this if this were a controller, but it appears that services are a whole different animal.

As a bit of background, I'm porting a working PHP application to Grails ... I'm a PHP guy, and this is my first forray into Grails, so I apologize if this is a noob question.

Comment: `mockSession` is a property of the `MvcUnitTestCase` class, not of `GroovyTestCase`.

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2.3.4:

```
import grails.util.GrailsWebUtil

class SomeTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testSomething() {
        def request = GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest()
        def myDummyObject = new DummyObject()
        request.session['myDummyObject'] = myDummyObject

        // Run your code and make asserts
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [MockUtils](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/test/MockUtils.groovy)

also try ControllerUnitTestCase

Comment: What do you mean by "take a look at"?

Comment: a ControllerUnitTestCase utilizes MockUtils which sets up the Session the request and the response more information here http://tomasjurman.blogspot.com/2010/08/grails-unit-testing.html